# How to fit data with square wave in Python?

Tags: python, data-science, physics, data-science-experience

I have the following data:

[Experimental data and ideal fitting function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfzdN.png)

I have been trying to fit it with a sequence of square pulses which I define as:

```
def f(x, x0, a, b, c):
    sq = a * np.ones_like(x)
    sq[(x>x0) * (x<x0+b)] = c
    sq[(x>x0+2*b) * (x<x0+3*b)] = c
    sq[(x>x0+4*b) * (x<x0+5*b)] = c
    return sq
```

The problem is that fitting with curve_fit I get a straight line or a square pulse whose max and min lie above the max of the data. How is this possible? How can I implement it properly?

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

What is your end goal, and is your approach the best way? I would think that you can Fourier transform your data to find the square wave Fourier coefficients. Taking the first *n* components and plotting the result will give you a periodic curve that is square-ish and "fits" the data.

Comment: My goal is to estimate the average value of the top regions and of the bottom regions. Obviously this could be done by hand but I have several of such plots with varying parameters for such square waves.